# error code is 'Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at'

Tags: multithreading, perl, shared

This is my code.

the code has some problem about hash shared.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %db;
share(%db);
my @threads;

sub test{
    my $db_ref = $_[0];
    my @arr = ('a','b');
    push @{$db_ref->{'key'}}, \@arr;
}

foreach(1..2){
    my $t = threads->new(
        sub {
            test(\%db);
        }
    );
    push(@threads,$t);
}

foreach (@threads) {
    $_->join;
}
```

error code.

```
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at test1.pl line 13.
Thread 2 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at test1.pl line 13.
```

I waana using threads::shared.

But I don`t know what is problem.

help me plz~

Answer (score 1):

You can only place references to shared objects into shared vars. `@arr` isn't shared, and neither is the array onto which you push a reference to `@arr`.

Replace

```
my @arr = ('a','b');
push @{$db_ref->{'key'}}, \@arr;
```

with

```
my @arr :shared = ('a','b');

lock %$db_ref;

# We can't use autovivification as we need a shared array.
$db_ref->{'key'} = shared_clone([]);

push @{$db_ref->{'key'}}, \@arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed code.
But can not save all data in hash(%db). Next code is check code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %db;
share(%db);
my @threads;

sub test{
    my $db_ref = $_[0];
    my @arr :shared = ('a','b');
    lock %$db_ref;
    $db_ref->{'key'} = shared_clone([]);
    push @{$db_ref->{'key'}}, \@arr;
}

foreach(1..5){
    my $t = threads->new(
        sub {
            test(\%db);
        }
    );
    push(@threads,$t);
}

foreach (@threads) {
    $_->join;
}

while(my ($key, $val) = each %db){
    print "$key => $val\n";
    foreach my $value (@$val) {
        foreach  (@$value) {
            print $_, " ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Only one data(a,b) in %db.
We must one more data in %db.